# Check equality of two expression "With Conditions"

Tags: simplifying-expressions, special-functions

I want to check if these equation holds if only if $t>0$
$$\frac 1t\left(-\gamma+\operatorname{Chi}(t)-\ln(t)-\operatorname{Shi}(t)\right)=\frac 1t\left(-\gamma+\operatorname{Ei}(-t)-\ln(t)\right),\quad t>0$$

```
In[14]:=
{(-EulerGamma + CoshIntegral[t] - Log[t] - SinhIntegral[t])/t, Assumptions -> 
t > 0 == (-EulerGamma + ExpIntegralEi[-t] - Log[t])/t, Assumptions -> t > 0} // Simplify
    
Out[14]=
{-((EulerGamma - CoshIntegral[t] + Log[t] + SinhIntegral[t])/t), Assumptions -> 
t > 0 && (EulerGamma - ExpIntegralEi[-t] + Log[t])/t == 0, Assumptions -> t > 0}
```

Can you help me? I've tried to read my possible duplicate but none of them are discussing about conditions. I know if i can use plot and if both graphs are overlapped then it's true, but maybe there is another efficient way to do this?

Comment: Try `FullSimplify[(-EulerGamma + CoshIntegral[t] - Log[t] - SinhIntegral[t])/t == (-EulerGamma + ExpIntegralEi[-t] - Log[t])/t, t > 0]` and report back.

Comment: @J.M. ok it works. Thanks

Comment: Since you want "if only if" you should look at both `FullSimplify[eqn, t > 0]` and `FullSimplify[eqn, t < 0]`

Comment: @BobHanlon Thanks for reply. What is eqn? And why there's $t<0$ since i only need iff $t>0$?

Comment: `eqn` is your equation. "if and **only** if t > 0" requires that it be `False` for `t < 0`, `FullSimplify[eqn, t < 0]` verifies that is satisfied.

Comment: @BobHanlon Nice! I understand. Thank you.